# NotNull not working with AddFieldToFilter in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, filter

I have following code to filter out rows on a column that is null and it is working

```
->addFieldToFilter(
            'ep_image',
            ['null' => true]
       )
```

and I have another code to filter out rows on a column that is not null which is not working

```
->addFieldToFilter(
            'ep_image',
            ['notnull' => true]
       )
```

Can anyone help me out on how to filter not null values?

Also tried `array('notnull' => true)`and `array('null' => false)`, but none working.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can try this

```
->addFieldToFilter(
            'ep_image',
            ['neq' => 'NULL']
       )
```

Comment: Thanks @userpk, that worked!!! Above code mentioned by me also worked, the issue was due to same variable being used by two different code.

Answer (score 2):

The followings work for me correctly:

> //IS NULL

```
->addFieldToFilter(
 'ep_image',
 array('null' => true)
```

> //IS NOT NULL

```
->addFieldToFilter(
 'ep_image',
 array('notnull' => true)
```